# How to solve AttributeError: 'Top2Vec' object has no attribute 'topic_sizes'?

Tags: python, attributeerror, topic-modeling

I am trying to work on top2vec model. When I run below lines of code I encountered

> AttributeError: 'Top2Vec' object has no attribute 'topic_sizes'

```
documents, document_scores, document_nums = top2vec.search_documents_by_topic(topic_num=344, num_docs=2)
    
result_df = Articles_df.loc[document_nums]
result_df["document_scores"] = document_scores

for index,row in result_df.iterrows():
    print(f"Document: {index}, Score: {row.document_scores}")
    print(f"Date: {row.Date}")
    print(f"Headline: {row.Headline}")
    print("-----------")
    print(row.Artciles)
    print("-----------")
    print()
```

Even though these lines have nowhere topic_sizes. For a full understanding, I am also providing whole shell of the error message.

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 documents, document_scores, document_nums = top2vec.search_documents_by_topic(topic_num=344, num_docs=2)
> 2
> 3 result_df = Articles_df.loc[document_nums]
> 4 result_df["document_scores"] = document_scores
> 5
>
> ~/PycharmProjects/News/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/top2vec/Top2Vec.py
> in search_documents_by_topic(self, topic_num, num_docs,
> return_documents, reduced)
> 983
> 984             self._validate_topic_num(topic_num, reduced)
> --> 985             self._validate_topic_search(topic_num, num_docs, reduced)
> 986
> 987             topic_document_indexes = np.where(self.doc_top == topic_num)[0]
>
> ~/PycharmProjects/News/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/top2vec/Top2Vec.py
> in _validate_topic_search(self, topic_num, num_docs, reduced)
> 489                                  f" only has {self.topic_sizes_reduced[topic_num]} documents.")
> 490         else:
> --> 491             if num_docs > self.topic_sizes[topic_num]:
> 492                 raise ValueError(f"Invalid number of documents: original topic {topic_num}"
> 493                                  f" only has {self.topic_sizes[topic_num]} documents.")
>
> AttributeError: 'Top2Vec' object has no attribute 'topic_sizes'

I am trying to use the pre-train model for top2vec and trying to analyze my own dataset.
I would appreciate any solutions or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on my data set and it is working, but I have 2 topics (0,1) and 796 of documnets are in topic 1 I did it like this: (otherwise I get error regarding number of topics and documents.)
`documents, document_scores, document_nums = modelx.search_documents_by_topic(topic_num=1,num_docs=796)`

Other rows are just like your code.

### output:
Document: 1468, Score: 0.3702481687068939
topic id : 2
Topic true name: mideast

### Legality of the Jewish Purchase (was   Israeli Expansion-lust) Right now, I'm just going to address this point

### Document: 1635, Score: 0.3487136960029602
topic id : 0
Topic true name: x

### Pulldown menu periodically hangs application on OpenWindows 3.0 : : Has anyone found a fix for the following problem?: : Client Software:   SunOs 4